# Primefaces fileDownload warning SRTServletResponse cannot set status

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websphere

I am using Primefaces to provide file download action in JSF. The code I am using is:

```
<p:commandButton id="xlsExport" value="Export XLS"
    ajax="false"
    onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(startPleaseWaitMonitor, stopPleaseWaitMonitor);">
    <p:fileDownload value="#{SampleBean.XLSExport}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

SampleBean has the following method:

```
public StreamedContent getXLSExport() {
    ...
    byte[] content = generator.generateXLS();
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(content), "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName, "UTF-8");
}
```

I am using it on two application servers - JBoss and Websphere. In case of Websphere I see warning in server logs when I do export:

> 000000f5 SRTServletRes W
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setStatus WARNING:
>   Cannot set status. Response already committed.

When I run similar method but for CSV export there is no warning. For JBoss there is no warning too.

What could be the reason for such log warning?

Comment: A 'similar' method for CSV works, so what **_IS_** the difference? "application/vnd.ms-excel" vs something else?

Comment: Just the content type: application/csv

Comment: What WebSphere version are you on?

Comment: I am on WAS 9.0

Answer (score 1):

I've recreated this locally - it appears that PrimeFaces' `FileDownloadActionListener` is attempting to set the response status code after that response has already been committed by the server.  The FileDownload code grabs the response output stream, writes the entire contents of the downloaded file to it, and then attempts to update the response status code.

WebSphere commits and flushes a response when the amount of data passed into the response buffer exceeds a certain threshold (by default 32K.)  Once the response has been committed, its headers (eg. status code) can't be updated.  The other application servers probably behave the same way here - they just might not log a warning message.  In this particular case the warning isn't anything to worry about, since the FileDownload code was just attempting to update the status code from 200 -> 200.

Using different content types (like `CSV`) shouldn't make a difference here.  File size does make a difference - if a file is downloaded that's less than the response buffer size, then the response won't be committed before the PrimeFaces code tries to set its status.

A simple fix for this warning message would be to check to see if the response is committed before attempting to change its status.  I've opened a PrimeFaces issue for this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3955

Update: I provided a fix to PrimeFaces, so you shouldn't see this anymore in the nightly builds/next version.

Comment: Compliments for the investigation. It might indeed explain why I never noticed it on Wildfly 7 or 10. W